# I can't load Plupload 2.1.2 in my ColdFusion page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

I'm seeing a Javascript error that's preventing PlUpload from working in my ColdFusion page. I've reduced the code down to the simplest example that shows the error. As you can see there isn't actually any ColdFusion in the code in this stripped down example. This is Plupload 2.1.2 that I'm using.

The html code below in a test.htm page loads without error. But if I change the file name to test.cfm it causes this javascript error:

"SyntaxError: missing } after property list" @ line 1056 column 14 in the jquery.ui.plupload.js file.

Firebug shows the live example as being "width: Â self.options.thumb_width,". It looks like "Â " is being inserted somehow in front of the "self.options.thumb_width" variable so it isn't being handled correctly.

I'm stymied; can anyone help?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.ui.plupload/css/jquery.ui.plupload.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working now. There seem to be two issues in the Plupload 2.1.2 download files that are easily fixed.

Fix 1: In the /js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js file, on line 1056 (in the "preloadThumb" function) - there is a double space that needs to be reduced to a single space. Removing the extra space fixes the issue so Plupload loads and runs as it should.

```
  "width:  self.options.thumb_width,"
needs to be changed to
  "width: self.options.thumb_width,".
```

Fix 2: The other way to fix this issue is to load the minimized version of the file (which pretty much strips out all blank space so the double-space issue is handled).

A problem I see in the Plupload 2.1.2 download is that all the examples load the unminimized version, even in the production section.

The production example should be 
"../../js/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.min.js"?

From the sample code head section:

```
<!-- production -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js"></script>

<!-- debug
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/moxie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/plupload.dev.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js"></script>
-->
```

So either fix above effectively solves the problem.

Comment: I meant well by the above reply to my own post but I've uncovered new facts and I think that the issue may be in my configuration of the server rather than with the JavaScript or ColdFusion code.

This JavaScript causes the same error on one set of three ColdFusion servers but NOT on any other CF servers that I have access to... These CF servers are mixed versions 9 and 11.

<script>
 var myVal = 25;
 var testVar = { width :  myVal };  // Two spaces between colon and value - it shouldn't matter
 alert(testVar.width);
</script>

Comment: The JS above causes an error in a test.cfm file but not in a test.htm file. It gives this error: SyntaxError: missing } after property list  --->  var testVar = { width : Â myVal }; (from Firebug). 

Is there something obvious that I have misconfigured in my ColdFusion or IIS installation?